# How to pass state to another component using useState() hook and history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a search bar, that when a user starts typing moves the user to a new view which shows the results on that view.

I have the following code which lets the user start searching, sets the `searchInput` into a state and moves the user to a new view.

**The problem is: I'm not able to pass and access the searchInput state from the SearchBar component to the SearchResultsView component.**

SearchBar.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const SearchBar = () => {

    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleInputChange = (value: string) => {
        setSearchInput(value);
        history.push('/search-results', { searchInput: searchInput });
    }

    return (
        <input
            type="text" 
            value={searchInput}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target.value)}   
        />
    )
}
```

Here is the SearchResultsView where I want to simply access the searchInput query (then I can proceed with building the search logic)

```
import * as React from 'react'

export const SearchResultsView = (searchInput) => {

    // What I've tried that didn't work
    const query = searchInput // returns empty
    const state = useState('searchInput') // returns empty

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Searching for: {searchInput} */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

For additional info, here's how I setup the `search-results` route

```
export const App = () =>  {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <AppSidebar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact render={() => <MainView/>}/>
            <Route path="/search-results" exact render={() => <SearchResultsView/>}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: How did you try to access state in SearchResultsView?

Comment: Updated question with what I've tried

Answer (score 1):

With `history.push`, you are trying to pass `searchInput` as state. Which can be accessed in the other component as `location.state`. But do note that `searchInput` is not set at the time you are passing it because setting state is an asynchronous process.

```
const handleInputChange = (value: string) => {
    setSearchInput(value);
    // searchInput is not yet set here, so using value
    history.push('/search-results', { searchInput: value });
}
```

If you want to set this from the state, you could use a `useEffect` for this purpose.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(searchInput) {
    history.push('/search-results', { searchInput });
  }
}, [searchInput]);
```

In both cases, you can access it with:

```
const location = useLocation();

// location.state would be undefined if user is directly taking this url
const { searchInput } = location.state || { searchInput: '' };
```

You can use query params if you want the user to link to the search page with param.

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-61106674-ttnj1)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still seeing location.state as undefined when implementing the useEffect hook and useLocation() hook in the results view.

Comment: @rock_n_rolla It's hard for me to tell what you are doing wrong, but added a codesandbox demo

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I have a clue what's going on. The project uses typescript, and I get the following warning when initialising the constant searchInput in the results component.

`Property 'searchInput' does not exist on type '{} | { searchInput: string; }'.ts(2339)`

So perhaps I need to setup a type for it?

Comment: yes, `useLocation` takes one type argument that you can pass into it. `useLocation<{ searchInput: string }>()`

Comment: searchInput is still always "none", so it's not being passed for some reason. Literally copied your code line for line too. Hmm.

Comment: Could it be something with how I setup the Route?

`<Route path="/search-results" exact render={() => <SearchResultsView/>}/>`

Comment: I don't think so, have you tried editing the codesandbox to include that?